# How to get Auto Dark Mode to work at sunset, not many hours later?

Tags: preferences, dark-mode

On Monterey 12.6.3 I have System Prefs > General > Appearance set to 'Auto'. This works, changing Dark to Light mode and back again automatically.

But it does so some hours after sunset.

I confirm Date & Time settings have me in the correct time zone (GMT) and Closest City is where I live.

Is there any way to make it work at around sunset, as Apple says it will?

Updates:

- still not correct on Ventura 13.6.1
- even more weird is that it has always worked as expected on my old Intel MacMini but not on my 2020 Apple Silicon MBA.

Comment: Try rebooting your mac in safe mode. Inform me of the evolution of the situation. :)

Comment: Literally hours? After 'official' sunset or when it gets dark? Also note that even at this time of year [near equinox] sunset in Brighton is 20 minutes ahead of Inverness… or to take it to extremes, Tenerife [also GMT] sunset today is an hour after Inverness.

Comment: @Tetsujin But the OP says that the nearest city is the one they're living in. Doesn't this prevent that kind of thing from happening?

Comment: @Tetsujin literally hours _after it gets dark_.